# Move ClickOnce repository without reinstall in client machines. Is it possible?

Tags: deployment, clickonce

I have a C# application (WinForms) (ClickOnce) whose repository is installed on a server that is about to crash, so my boss asked me to move the repository, but there are around 300 client machines which have the application installed.

The ClickOnce is signed with a Test Certificate.

Is it possible to move the repository without having to reinstall in the client machines?

Thanks in Advance

**[EDIT]**

I Have published the application to the new server, but the clients don't reach it, what else can I do? I think i should change something inside the manifest or something like that, but a actually don't know too much about ClickOnce... In any case, i would like to avoid the reinstallation on all the client machines, any ideas, suggestion? thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I have done, for people who may have the same issue.

- Setup the new server on the publish package. (Project Properties, Publish Tab)
- Publish to the new server
- Copy the published files to the old server. (Include the .application file and the folder)

When the clients reach the old server, they will update, but the server location will be updated on the client to the new server name.

Answer (score 3):

The answer provided by Jhonny seemed promising to me, and I encountered an error when I tried it, which I had to solve. It had to do with certificates.

After following his setps, when I launch the ClickOnce app on the client machine, I get an error dialog: "Cannot Start Application".

When I click on the Details... button in the error dialog, the text file that opens shows that the app is trying to update from the Deployment Provider URL of the new server, but it gives this error:

"The deployment identity does not match the subscription."

The problem was the certificate used to publish the app on the old server was expired, and I had updated the certificate in the app published on the new server. The certificates didn't match.

The solution was to first publish the app to the old server with the new certificate, have the users open the app to get that update, then publish another new version with the Deployment URL of the new server, and copy the files to both servers. When the users updated the next time, they got the version of the app from the old server with the manifest pointing to the new server, and then, all subsequents updates were retrieved from the new server.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to change the DNS alias so that it redirects to your new server.

The fact that the code signed using a certificate is not relevant, since code-signing certificates are not bound to a specific repository (as opposed to SSL certificates)

Btw, why don't you want to reinstall? The whole point of clickonce is to ease this kind of software update !!

Comment: But i actually need to move the repository, the movement is planned and the server currently hosts other applications so i would say i don't have control over the server.

Comment: If the server is about to crash, why not replacing it totally by a new one with the same dns name? In case you're not in a position to take that decision, you may want to redirect your repository URL to another server

Comment: The reinstall via clickonce is usually automatic, we fear that, when we change the repository url, that oblies us to reinstall on every machine.

Comment: Definitely not. just change your clickonce application so that it uses another repository (ie the new one). really, I think you're overcomplicating your situation. deploying a new version on the old repository targeting the new repository as the install repository WILL work